# ng-class not overriding class as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of icons that are either "on" or "off" depending on boolean values in the $scope. I created two CSS classes -- clrOn and clrOff -- and they are only different colors. I am assigning all of the icons clrOff using class="" and then trying to override that with ng-class="" if the boolean is true.

Based on my research, this is what I have that should work. 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W2fFxkt0oGcp7AUBbX6U?p=preview)

CSS FILE:

```
.clrOn { color: #333333; }
.clrOff { color: #DDDDDD; }
```

JS FILE:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.attachments = 1;
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span class="clrOff" 
          tooltip="Attachments" 
          ng-class="{ 'clrOn' : app.attachments }">
          TEST
    </span>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing, `ng-class="{ 'clrOn' : app.attachments }"` is not picking up the attachments variable since it's declared directly on scope and not on scope.app so change that to `ng-class="{ 'clrOn' : attachments }"`.

Second, `ng-class` will not override any existing `class` attributes, but add to them so your span will be left with having both classes applied to it. If you dont want to have both classes assigned you'll need to declare them both using `ng-class`.

Comment: And so, just swap the two CSS declarations. Or use `ng-class="attachments ? 'clrOn' : 'clrOff'"`

Comment: Or if there's more classes on the way, `ng-class="{ clrOn : attachments, clrOff: !attachments }"`

Comment: Sorry about the "app." part, in my real world project, a list of icons belongs to a record in an ng-repeat of app in applications but I tried to simplify it for plunker. However, none of these are working for me if I changed my REAL declaration to this: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" tooltip="Attachments" ng-class="{clrOn : app.attachments, clrOff : !app.attachments }"></span>

Comment: Sorry again. It absolutely DOES work. In my project, I didn't change the second attachments to app.attachments so it was applying both classes. Thanks!